# Export HTML table and form data to Excel using Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page which has a from and two tables, the data are fetched from MySQL. I want to export the form and the tables data to  Excel using Jquery Plugin.

I have used the following Jquery Plugin. But, it exports only the table data, form data is omitted.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html

```
<form id="ex1>
  <label>Roll No 2</label>
  <input type="text value="Anil">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text value="Anil">
  <label>Dept</label>
  <input type="text value="CSE">
</form>

<table id="ex2>
  <tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Mark</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>69</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Maths</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Computer</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Export

```
<script>
  $("#export").click(function(){
     $("body").table2excel({
        exclude: ".noExl",
        name: "Worksheet Name",
        filename: "Employee Details",
        fileext: ".xls", 
        exclude_img: true,
        exclude_links: true,
       exclude_inputs: true
   }); 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `form` data into html `table` with `tr td` format.

Answer (score 0):

As [Tabrosh Shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552716/tabrosh-shaikh) suggested you will have to add form data in table.

You can add hidden rows in the table with `style="display:none;"` and copy the `form` values into these `table` rows on the `click` event of `#export`. So these rows will not be visible on the UI but will get exported in the excel.